# How do I compile this into an executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I just need to compile this into a .exe so I can use it with command line.
Its just a Audio converter that converts .adx to wav, just need it for a few files and Never-compiled-anything-me is finding this a difficult endeavor, I really dont want to give up this adventure, so going to suck it up and ask for help.

I'm mainly interested in the "test" folder, according to the [readme](https://gitlab.kode54.net/kode54/vgmstream), all I need is the Test.exe.

[extracted.zip](http://imgur.com/a/5EwvW) contents (already moved over the .dlls as per readme) 
Initially I googled the basics, got Visual Studio 2015 (latest)
loaded up the `.vcxproj` and Build > compile 'test.c' in Source Files, but I got an error saying I was missing or needed to install the build tool set for `VC2010` (v100), so googling it I hunted down that I needed Visual Studio 2010, Now that I finally have that, getting a different error. (.vcproj)

> C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(511,5):
>   error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v140) is not installed or
>   invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is
>   selected. 1> 1>Build FAILED.

Just getting stumped left and right, could really use just a finger to point me in the right direction, not really asking for someone to compile the exe for me because I believe its better to teach a man to fish than give him a fish. Would just like to know how to solve this for now and for future.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile a project that specifies the use of a v140 project (Visual Studio 2015). However, you are running Visual Studio 2010.

You can try to do this though. Right-click on the project and select Properties. Under Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset, select v100. Try and compile again.

If this doesn't work, you will need to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thats odd, as I mentioned I first tried in VS 2015 but then was getting an error about needing VS 2010  well Tried compile again after your suggestion Build Success, but output file is a .obj file...?